# hover in one div that trigger the effect hover in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a problem: I have an effect hover in one div, but I would like to trigger the effect when the cursor is hover another div. Something like:

```
<div id='mouse-hover-in-this-div'>
    blablabla
    <div id='should-trigger-mouse-hover-in-this-div'></div>
</div>
```

I see some solutions here but they did not work. In particular I tried to change the css property of the inner div with the jquery .css method but I did not succed in giving the following option:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(16px);
transform: translateY(16px);
-webkit-animation-name: hang;
animation-name: hang;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
animation-delay: 0.3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
animation-direction: alternate;
```

The hover I want to assing is from the library hover.css, I simply want that a bounce effect of an arrow is triggered when the whole div is hover, not just the little arrow.
There is a solution to my problem?

Comment: Could you make JSFiddle?

Comment: you can use css `#mouse-hover-in-this-div:hover #should-trigger-mouse-hover-in-this-div { ..... }`

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/7a0e3cfw/

Comment: this is my fiddle: the result I want to achieve is that placeing the cursor hover the sentence "this is some text" the effect hover on the arrow is triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/a0xx6kqa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a0xx6kqa/3/)

```
#outside-box:hover .animated-div {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
  transform: translateY(6px);
  -webkit-animation-name: hang;
  animation-name: hang;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For html

```
  <div id='mouse-hover-in-this-div'>
        blablabla
        <div id='should-trigger-mouse-hover-in-this-div'></div>
    </div>
```

you can have css like

```
#mouse-hover-in-this-div:hover #should-trigger-mouse-hover-in-this-div{
 //HOver Css here 
}
```

see a working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jdksbg51/

Comment: This actually works, but I have more than one div before the inner div. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0xx6kqa/2/
In this situation this solution does not work anymore. Sorry I forgot to mention that in first place...

Comment: you can give the id of which ever class you want to hover supose you have parent -> child -> subchild , and you want to chaneg css of subchild, then just do #parent:hover #sub-child-id{}

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bouncer effect you will need to add jQueryUI effects as well as the jQuery  library

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using CSS [descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) to select `#inner-div` when you hover on `#outside-box` div.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ee3pm7ey/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id='outside-box'>this is some text
    <div id="another-div">
        <div id='inner-div' class='animated-div'>-></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#another-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.animated-div {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#outside-box:hover .animated-div, #outside-box:focus .animated-div, #outside-box:active .animated-div {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
    transform: translateY(6px);
    -webkit-animation-name: hang;
    animation-name: hang;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$('#mouse-hover-in-this-div').hover(function(e) {
$('#should-trigger-mouse-hover-in-this-div').trigger(e.type);
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gLsqyts1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are based on your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a0xx6kqa/4/

When you hover over the parent element it will search for the child with class .animated-div and will animate that div no matter how many other elements you have in the parent :)

```
.animated-div {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#outside-box:hover .animated-div {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
    transform: translateY(6px);
    -webkit-animation-name: hang;
    animation-name: hang;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Just add #outside-box:hover .animated-div where you call the animations instead of the rest of the classes

.animated-div:hover, .animated-div:focus, .animated-div:active {} should just be **#outside-box:hover .animated-div** {}